# DateTime is not recognized

Tags: asp.net, datetime, calendar

FormatException was unhandled by user code.
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // to simulate a database query
        socialEvents = new DataTable();
        socialEvents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));
        socialEvents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
        socialEvents.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Url", typeof(string)));

        DataRow row;
        row = socialEvents.NewRow();
        row["Date"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5);
        row["Description"] = "Work";
        row["Url"] = "http://www.url.cz";
        socialEvents.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Error in the following methode:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            **DataRow[] rows = socialEvents.Select(
             String.Format(
                "Date >= #{0}# AND Date < #{1}#",
                e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString(),
                e.Day.Date.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()**
             )
          );
```

Comment: works fine when I run it on my system, but i replaced e.Day.Date with datetime.now

Comment: I also replace it but it doen't work

Comment: Did you have any idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use LINQ to do this:

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    var rows = socialEvents.Rows.Cast<DataRow>
               .Where(r => (DateTime)r["Date"] >= e.Day.Date 
                           && (DateTime)r["Date"] <= e.Day.Date.AddDays(1))
               .ToArray();
);
```

There is no more hassle with string formatted queries: you can use a filter based on real values.

Of course, if Date can be null, you will have to handle this. Just tell and I will edit this code if needed.

Comment: how do I do the following with linq?
DataView view = socialEvents.DefaultView;
        view.RowFilter = String.Format(
                          "Date >= #{0}# AND Date < #{1}#",
                          Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString(),
                          Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString()
                       );

Comment: var filteredRows = socialEvents.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => (DateTime)r["Date"] >= Calendar1.SelectedDate && (DateTime)r["Date"] < Calendar1.SelectedDate.AddDays(1)).ToArray(); Then bind your grid with filteredRows as a new DataSource. You can also sort records with the OrderBy() linq extension method.